# Trigger a click on previous sibling with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to trigger a click on a checkbox when the text next to the checkbox is clicked ("Finance department" or "Sales department" in the snippet).

I have tried with both jquery and javascript but any of those two seem to work:

```
$(prevsibling).children().click();
$(prevsibling).children().trigger("click");
```

Please find attached a snippet with the code.

Any clue ?

Thanks a lot

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {

  clickeditem = $(e.target);

  if (clickeditem.hasClass('checkboxinfotd')) {
    prevsibling = $(clickeditem).prev()[0];
    $(prevsibling).children().click();

  } else if (clickeditem.hasClass('checkboxtd') || clickeditem.hasClass('checkbutton')) {
    if (clickeditem.hasClass('checkboxtd')) {
      clickeditem = clickeditem.children()[0];
    } else if (clickeditem.hasClass('checkbutton')) {

    } else {

    }

    console.log("clicked on checkbox");
    thirdclass = clickeditem.attr('class').split(' ')[2];

    if (thirdclass === "fa-square-o") {
      newclass = 'fa-check-square-o';
      clickeditem.removeClass("fa-square-o");
      clickeditem.addClass(newclass);

    } else if (thirdclass === "fa-check-square-o") {
      newclass = 'fa-square-o';
      clickeditem.removeClass("fa-check-square-o");
      clickeditem.addClass(newclass)
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.checkboxinfotd {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Table id="belowtable">
  <tbody class="scenariotbody">
    <TR>
      <TD colspan="2">
        Text
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD class="checkboxtd"><i class="checkbutton fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true" id="plan-282"></i>
      </TD>
      <TD class="checkboxinfotd">Finance department</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD class="checkboxtd"><i class="checkbutton fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true" id="plan-289"></i>
      </TD>
      <TD class="checkboxinfotd">Sales department</TD>
    </TR>
  </tbody>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using: `clickeditem.closest('tr').find('.checkbutton').trigger('mouseup');`

This code finds the table row parent. Inside the parent it looks for the element with the `checkbutton` class and triggers the mouseup event (your code is bound to `mouseup` not `click`)

---

*As others already stated it might be wise to abonden the idea of using font awsome for checkboxes and use the html `input` and `label` elements instead and style those with css. This will make your life a lot easier handling your inputs.*

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {

  clickeditem = $(e.target);

  if (clickeditem.hasClass('checkboxinfotd')) {
    clickeditem.closest('tr').find('.checkbutton').trigger('mouseup');

  } else if (clickeditem.hasClass('checkboxtd') || clickeditem.hasClass('checkbutton')) {
    if (clickeditem.hasClass('checkboxtd')) {
      clickeditem = clickeditem.children()[0];
    } else if (clickeditem.hasClass('checkbutton')) {

    } else {

    }

    console.log("clicked on checkbox");
    thirdclass = clickeditem.attr('class').split(' ')[2];

    if (thirdclass === "fa-square-o") {
      newclass = 'fa-check-square-o';
      clickeditem.removeClass("fa-square-o");
      clickeditem.addClass(newclass);

    } else if (thirdclass === "fa-check-square-o") {
      newclass = 'fa-square-o';
      clickeditem.removeClass("fa-check-square-o");
      clickeditem.addClass(newclass)
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.checkboxinfotd {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Table id="belowtable">
  <tbody class="scenariotbody">
    <TR>
      <TD colspan="2">
        Text
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD class="checkboxtd"><i class="checkbutton fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true" id="plan-282"></i>
      </TD>
      <TD class="checkboxinfotd">Finance department</TD>
      <TD class="checkboxinfotd">Sales department</TD>
    </TR>
  </tbody>
</Table>
```

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks a lot for your answer and comments. Well noted for your proposition. I will try to stick to labels next time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear completely. Would you trigger the checkbox by click on the text on the right side?
If yes, please use label.

```css
/* Control the label position from here */
.control {
    font-family: inherit;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: inherit;
}
    .control input {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        opacity: 0;
    }
.control_indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #008736;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.control:hover input ~ .control_indicator,
.control input:focus ~ .control_indicator {
    background: #cccccc;
}

.control input:checked ~ .control_indicator {
    background: #008736;
}
.control:hover input:not([disabled]):checked ~ .control_indicator,
.control input:checked:focus ~ .control_indicator {
    background: #008736;
}
.control input:disabled ~ .control_indicator {
    background: #008736;
    opacity: 0.6;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.control_indicator:after {
    box-sizing: unset;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.control input:checked ~ .control_indicator:after {
    display: block;
}
.control-checkbox .control_indicator:after {
    left: 8px;
    top: 4px;
    width: 3px;
    height: 8px;
    border: solid #ffffff;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.control-checkbox input:disabled ~ .control_indicator:after {
    border-color: #008736;
}
.control-checkbox .control_indicator::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 4.5rem;
    height: 4.5rem;
    margin-left: -1.3rem;
    margin-top: -1.3rem;
    background: #008736;
    border-radius: 3rem;
    opacity: 0.6;
    z-index: 99999;
    transform: scale(0);
}

/* The ripple effect  */
@keyframes s-ripple {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    20% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@keyframes s-ripple-dup {
   0% {
       transform: scale(0);
    }
   30% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    60% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
.control-checkbox input + .control_indicator::before {
    animation: s-ripple 250ms ease-out;
}
.control-checkbox input:checked + .control_indicator::before {
    animation-name: s-ripple-dup;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control control-checkbox">
        label
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
        <div class="control_indicator"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Shahidul. Correct, yes

Comment: Hello, Please use checkboxs instead of fontawesome. 
Fontawesome is not appropriate for this kind of work.

I added s example with the style of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you ultimatly want is to see the fake "checkbox" check/uncheck so I gave an example of toggling that class pair no matter where on the row you click.

```js
$('#belowtable')
  .on('click', '.checkboxinfotd', function(e) {
    let clickeditem = $(this)
    let myparent = clickeditem.closest('tr')
      .find('.checkboxtd')
      .trigger('click');
  }).on('click', '.checkboxtd', function(e) {
    let clickeditem = $(this);
    let cb = clickeditem.find('.checkbutton.fa');
    cb.toggleClass('fa-square-o').toggleClass('fa-check-square');
  });
```

```css
.checkboxinfotd {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="belowtable">
  <tbody class="scenariotbody">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        Text
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="checkboxtd"><i class="checkbutton fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true" id="plan-282"></i>
      </td>
      <td class="checkboxinfotd">Finance department</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="checkboxtd"><i class="checkbutton fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true" id="plan-289"></i>
      </td>
      <td class="checkboxinfotd">Sales department</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```